# XAML Forms not recognizing local and referenced classes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I opened a VS 2012 Solution in VS 2015 and cannot get it to compile. It was originally targeting .Net 3.5 and used the WPF Toolkit, which caused some ambiguous references. I resolved that by removing the reference to the WPF Toolkit and replacing it with the package DotNetProjects.Wpf.Toolkit.
Now I have to tackle the next issue, which I suspect is not caused by the obvious but is a cascade from some other hidden gotcha from upgrading the versions.
My XAML forms are not recognizing the existence of classes within referenced namespaces. I can get them to come up on intellisense but the application won't compile and the error says something like: "The name "MainWindow" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:FieldSheetPrinter".

I have defined my main form with the following:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FieldSheetPrinter"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:validationRules="clr-namespace:SWallTech.ValidationSupport;assembly=SWallTech.ValidationSupport"
xmlns:FieldSheetPrinter_Converters="clr-namespace:FieldSheetPrinter.Converters"
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:SWallTech.WPF.Support.Converters;assembly=SWallTech.WPF.Support"
x:Class="FieldSheetPrinter.MainWindow"
x:Name="MainWindow"
Title="CAMRA Field Sheet Printer - Stonewall Technologies, Inc."
Width="744"
Height="583"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
Icon="CamraPrint.ico">
```

I have references to the SWallTech.WPF.Support project, which is in the solution, and the compiler has no problem recognizing the classes in that project's *Converters* namespace. This code has no error indicator. (Red squiggles.)

```
<Converters:IntGreaterThanZeroToVisibilityConverter 
  x:Key="IntGreaterThanZeroToVisibilityConverter" />
<Converters:DatabaseConnectionImageSourceConverter
  x:Key="DatabaseConnectionImageSourceConverter" />
```

However if I try to refer to the ViewModel I am using as the datasource, I get an error:

```
<local:FieldSheetPrinterViewModel 
        x:Key="FieldSheetPrinterViewModelDataSource"
        d:IsDataSource="True" />
```

I also get the error that the XAML form itself is not in the namespace FieldSheetPrinter, which of course it is, as you can see from the Code-Behind.

```
namespace FieldSheetPrinter
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
 ...
 }
```

I have tried everything I can think of, and I am truly stumped.
Joey

Comment: If a class doesn't compile, the XAML designer will try to pretend it doesn't exist at all, which seems passive-aggressive of it. That's one possibility here.

Comment: I did that. And I did find some places where some of the referenced classes had issues. I built each independently and determined that they were all valid. I do think that is is something passive aggressive about the WPF libraries, I just don't know how to fix it!

Comment: I *think* I have it working. At least it is compiling...Though the designer still seems unsure of its validity. I will post the answer I think solved it below, but I can't say for sure it wasn't something else. I tried a lot of things in a short time frame.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, the problem wasn't directly with the XAML, or at least not completely. The original developer had named the Window tag with the same name as the code-behind class name, and that seems to be prohibited now. That was the only issue with the XAML. Everything else had to do with overlaps in the WPF and Windows.System.Data libraries that caused IValueConverter (in the System.Windows.Data namespace) to go unrecognized. I eliminated any other references that could have conflicted, and corrected some syntax issues in the code-behind that apparently were deprecated.

Ex.

```
stringVariable.IsNullOrEmpty()
```

was used instead of

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringVariable)
```

In other places some ObservableCollection objects weren't recognized as enumerable, so I had to add "ToList()" before looping through the collection.

Weird, but I didn't write this stuff!

Thanks for the suggestions.

Joey